docker in docker jenkins agent
`I am trying to use docker in docker. This is a first experience so it's very difficult for me.
My Scenario:
1- I created dind container with follow jenkins.io documentation:
docker run \   --name jenkins-docker \   --rm \   --detach \   --privileged \   --network jenkins \   --network-alias docker \   --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \   --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client \   --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \   --publish 2376:2376 \   docker:dind \   --storage-driver overlay2
2- I created jenkins container:
docker run \   --name jenkins-blueocean \   --restart=on-failure \   --detach \   --network jenkins \   --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \   --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client \   --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \   --publish 8080:8080 \   --publish 50000:50000 \   --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \   --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \   myjenkins-blueocean:2.452.3-1
3- I imported dummy data for new jenkins.
It's excellent this point.
What is my issue:
I want to create several different jenkins agent. For example in normally I create jenkins agent with below dockerfile:
`**FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq tzdata && ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Istanbul /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y git gcc g++ make cmake meson sharutils libssl-dev binutils libev-dev libuv1-dev libevent-dev vim less curl wget openjdk-17-jre openjdk-17-jdk openssh-server openssh-client zip libopencv-dev libeigen3-dev libboost-all-dev libyaml-cpp-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev pkg-config libgtk-3-dev libglfw3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev at sudo
RUN curl -sO http://192.168.64.61:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar
COPY jenkins-slave.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/jenkins-slave.sh"] **` jenkins-slave.sh include java -jar command and include secret text etc.
I want to create an agent using this dockerfile, but let the agent be like this:
Pİpeline starts to work, the agent starts working. And the pipeline ends, the agent turns itself off.
When the pipeline starts to work, the agent starts working, and when the pipeline ends, the agent turns itself off. I did a lot of research. I could not separate the theoretical part and do the practical part. Can you please explain step by step what not to do about this? Thank you for your support.``
`When the pipeline starts to work, the agent starts working, and when the pipeline ends, the agent turns itself off. I did a lot of research. I could not separate the theoretical part and do the practical part. Can you please explain step by step what not to do about this? Thank you for your support.```
